# Removing a KDS-37 Kitchenaid fisher

Tags: dishwasher

[How to remove an old KitchenAid dishwasher?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/11418/109446)

The unit is exactly like the one in the picture in the hyperlink above and below. The screws in the left
side have been removed and the unit will still not budge. Any suggestions? It’s as if the unit is secured by screws that are not accessible or visible.

[How to remove an old KitchenAid dishwasher?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/11418/109446)

Comment: Did you have access to remove four screws from the left side? The various pictures seem to indicate that the washer is assembled as a unit onto that metal frame structure that extends out to the left side under the sink tub.

Comment: Most of the time there are 2 screws in the top front opening just under the counter ledge look there for 2 or possibly more screws.

Comment: There are two hard to reach screws that are next to the sink bowl. Would it be difficult to take the counter top off to get to the screws?