# Replacing a KitchenAid Superba KDC-37 SST that is part of an Electric Sink

Tags: electrical, kitchens, sink, dishwasher, retrofit

I'm removing my old Kitchenaid Superba by Hobart model KDC-37 SST.  This came as one unit that consists of the cabinet, dishwasher and sink/drainboard.  All new dishwashers are not really slide in compatible.  Does anyone have any experience retrofitting?  I'm trying to avoid buying a modern cabinet.

Comment: *cough* https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/11418/how-to-remove-an-old-kitchenaid-dishwasher

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](https://www.automaticwasher.org/cgi-bin/TD/TD-VIEWTHREAD.cgi?31709) it should be possible, with some effort, to remove the dishwasher. If you do it carefully then the empty space should be suitable for a modern dishwasher.

I would first measure the dimensions - height, width and depth - and compare to installation specs on a modern dishwasher. If the specs match (old larger than new is OK, but if new is larger than old then you have a problem) then it will just be a matter of figuring out how to get the old one out. If regular tools don't do it, there's always a [Sawzall](https://amzn.to/47ZhLa4):

[image]

If I remember correctly, my parents had a similar Kitchenaid dishwasher (late 1970s) but installed in a regular cabinet. It would be strange, but not impossible, for Kitchenaid to make entirely different dishwashers for the integrated sink/dishwasher "Electric Sink".